# Book cover formatting

Tags: formatting

So I was trying to design a book cover but I had to list some item on the coverpage but Idk why it's not compiling as it should with the code.

This is how it turns out

[image]

but I need the below items to be in a list like this

[image]

also why aren't the checkmarks showing up?

This is the code:

```tex
    \documentclass{article}
    
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{ shapes.geometric }
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usepackage{anyfontsize}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    
    
    \begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[BrickRed] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
    
    
    \foreach \i in {2.5,...,22}
    {
        \node[rounded corners,BrickRed!60,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=\i cm,ultra thick] at ($(current page.west)+(2.5,-5)$) {} ;
    }
    
    \foreach \i in {0.5,...,22}
    {
    \node[rounded corners,BrickRed!60,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=\i cm,ultra thick] at ($(current page.north west)+(2.5,0)$) {} ;
    }
    
    \foreach \i in {0.5,...,22}
    {
    \node[rounded corners,BrickRed!90,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=\i cm,ultra thick] at ($(current page.north east)+(0,-9.5)$) {} ;
    }
    
    
    \foreach \i in {21,...,6}
    {
    \node[BrickRed!85,rounded corners,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=\i cm,ultra thick] at ($(current page.south east)+(-0.2,-0.45)$) {} ;
    }
    
    
    \node[left,BrickRed!5,minimum width=0.625*\paperwidth,minimum height=3cm, rounded corners] at ($(current page.north east)+(0,-9.5)$)
    {
    {\fontsize{25}{30} \selectfont \bfseries 100 Thrilling Math Problems}
    };
    
    \node[left,BrickRed!10,minimum width=0.625*\paperwidth,minimum height=2cm, rounded corners] at ($(current page.north east)+(0,-11)$)
    {
    {\huge \textit{Both Textual and Video Solutions}}
    };
    
    \node[left,BrickRed!5,minimum width=0.625*\paperwidth,minimum height=2cm, rounded corners] at ($(current page.north east)+(1,-13)$)
    {
    {\fontsize{25}{30} \textsc{By Kowshiq Kattamuri}}
    };
    
    \node[left,BrickRed!5,minimum width=0.625*\paperwidth,minimum height=2cm, rounded corners] at ($(current page.north east)+(1,-16)$)
    {
    \begin{itemize}
        \item [\checkmark] Jee Advanced
        \item [\checkmark] ISI
        \item [\checkmark] CMI
        \item [\checkmark] KVPY
        \item [\checkmark] IOQM
    \end{itemize}
    };
    
    
    
    \node[rounded corners,fill=BrickRed!70,text =BrickRed!5,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=2.5 cm,inner sep=0,ultra thick] at ($(current page.west)+(2.5,-5)$) {\LARGE \bfseries };
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `text width=<length>` to allow line breaking inside nodes, and then with `align=right` to align your text to the right side.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ shapes.geometric }
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\newcommand{\KKcheckmark}{\enspace\textcolor{Green!60}{\checkmark}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[BrickRed] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);


\node[rounded corners,fill=BrickRed!70,text =BrickRed!5,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=2.5 cm,inner sep=0,ultra thick] at ($(current page.west)+(2.5,-5)$) {\LARGE \bfseries };

\foreach \i in {2.5,...,22}
{
    \node[rounded corners,BrickRed!60,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=\i cm,ultra thick] at ($(current page.west)+(2.5,-5)$) {} ;
}

\foreach \i in {0.5,...,22}
{
\node[rounded corners,BrickRed!60,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=\i cm,ultra thick] at ($(current page.north west)+(2.5,0)$) {} ;
}

\foreach \i in {0.5,...,22}
{
\node[rounded corners,BrickRed!90,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=\i cm,ultra thick] at ($(current page.north east)+(0,-9.5)$) {} ;
}

\foreach \i in {21,...,6}
{
\node[BrickRed!85,rounded corners,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=\i cm,ultra thick] at ($(current page.south east)+(-0.2,-0.45)$) {} ;
}


\node[left, BrickRed!5, text width=0.625*\paperwidth, align=right, minimum height=3cm, rounded corners] at ($(current page.north east)+(-1,-9.5)$)
{
{\fontsize{25}{30} \selectfont \bfseries 100 Thrilling Math Problems}
};

\node[left,BrickRed!10, text width=0.625*\paperwidth, align=right, minimum height=2cm, rounded corners] at ($(current page.north east)+(-1,-11)$)
{
{\huge \textit{Both Textual and Video Solutions}}
};

\node[left, BrickRed!5, text width=0.625*\paperwidth, align=right, minimum height=2cm, rounded corners] at ($(current page.north east)+(-1,-13)$)
{
{\fontsize{25}{30} \textsc{By Kowshiq Kattamuri}}
};

\node[left, BrickRed!5, text width=0.625*\paperwidth, align=right, minimum height=2cm, rounded corners] at ($(current page.north east)+(-1,-19)$)
{
\LARGE
Jee Advanced\KKcheckmark\\
ISI\KKcheckmark\\
CMI\KKcheckmark\\
KVPY\KKcheckmark\\
IOQM\KKcheckmark\\
};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok that solves my query but how to make the list look a little bit bigger

Comment: @TheSocialPi I use the font size `\LARGE`, you can apply a bigger size like those in the previous nodes.

Comment: okay thanks a lot for the help @jinwen